# SVR predict average value but train perfectly

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, regression, svm

I have been using SVR to predict the value of a time series. My dataset is split into two which is train and test and using SVR with RBF kernel to predict the test dataset. While SVR has been perfectly modeled the train data set but always predict the average value of the test dataset.

Have been trying StandardScaller, Normalization and so on but always failed.

here is my code

```
X = np.array(x).reshape(-1,1)
Y = np.array(y).reshape(-1,1)
sc_y = StandardScaler()
Y = sc_y.fit_transform(Y)
Y = np.array(Y).ravel()
# Fit regression model
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, 
test_size=0.4, random_state=0, shuffle=False)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=10, gamma=9.9999999999999995e-08, epsilon=0.1)
print(X_train.shape)
svr_rbf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_rbf = svr_rbf.predict(X_train)
y_rbf1 = svr_rbf.predict(X_test)
```

and here is my result [image]

The prediction is at the end where a constant value is shown.

Do you know what should I do to make the prediction better?